# Best practice deploy web application calling script retrieve stdout

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a REST web service in Java that needs to call a Perl script. The Perl script takes a text file and returns output on stdout. I have a Dockerfile for this Perl script. I also have Dockerfile for the Java application. Ideally I would be able to scale the web service and the script independently based on load. What is a best practice solution for this? Do I:

- Create a single pod with both. If so, how do I scale this independently? If that's not an option, how do I handle keep the web service running when  the Perl script gets overloaded (e.g. runs out of memory).
- Create two pods. How do I handle communication between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pod is the minimum deployable unit in Kubernetes, which is an scheduler of resources. That being said, if you need to scale those applications independently, you need to use two pods. Otherwise, they will belong to the same Pod, which is the thing that you scale up/down in kubernetes (normally, you use a `Deployment` object to do that).

Ideally, the Java application would connect to the perl application through the network using a `Service` object, which lets you expose a Pod to the rest of the cluster using a specific name.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! For the last part - does that mean I would have to create some rest service on top of the perl application?

Comment: Yeah, ideally. I guess you could write the output to a file into a volume and mount the same volume in both pods. But an http/grpc API would be easier I believe.